# Generate models and end-point using swagger specification with mironaut 3.6.0 and angular application 14

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger, openapi, micronaut

I have two separate applications, one is Micronaut using Java and Angular 14. They are two independent applications. Using the benefit of open API I am generating the Swagger UI using Micronaut [swagger](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-openapi/latest/guide/) dependency as shown below

[image]

Micronuat generates the swagger specification YAML file inside the build directory as shown below

[image]

Now, I want to generate the typescript files for the angular application using the swagger specification file.

**What is the best approx to create typescript files and how to consume them on the front-end application?**

**Or is there a way to expose the files to angular typescript or javascript from swagger UI using Micronaut?**

Reference [Using Swagger to Connect a Backend to an Angular Frontend](https://dzone.com/articles/using-swagger-to-connect-a-backend-to-an-angular-f)

Comment: Ok, so that's what you want to do. What's your question?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular the question is What is the best approx to create typescript files and how to consume them on the front-end application ?

Comment: best == opinionated

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the backend and the frontend would be separated. You would download the OpenAPI YAML file and use it in the frontend project to generate some kind of Javascript/Typescript HTTP client and include it in your source code. In some projects, I saw it automated by a script that can download the specification from some test environment and regenerate the client.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [swagger codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) project in the swagger API project

We need to download the jar from [swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.34.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/codegen/v3/swagger-codegen-cli/3.0.34/swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.34.jar) or [maven](https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.swagger.codegen.v3/swagger-codegen-cli/3.0.34/jar)

Run your backend application and point the `swagger.yaml` file as below

```
java -jar tools/swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.34.jar generate \
  -i http://localhost:8080/swagger/fete-bird-api-gateway-0.0.yml \
  -l typescript-angular \
  -o /libs/service/src/lib/swagger-specification \
  -Dmodels -DmodelDocs=false \
  -c tools/angular-swagger-option.json
```

**angular-swagger-option.json**

```
{
  "ngVersion": "14.0.5"
}
```